# How can I switch retina to non-retina in OS X with cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Hello I'm OS X beginner.

I use MacBook Pro retina 13 2013 late.
I need retina to non-retina switch in my menu-bar
so, I tried to make this app...
but I don't know how change my display resolution..

I find this article.. but short time blinking and change resolution, after back to original setting..

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004234-SW1

but I don't know it is right solution.

I want make exactly same as OS X's display setting retina to non-retina and non-retina to retina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code in that article shows both switching the display mode and then switching it back. There's a placeholder comment for you could put code to display something in between the mode switches, but if you don't do anything there it will just immediately switch back.

It sounds like you want to switch the display mode and leave it that way. You want that to affect the desktop and all apps, so you don't want to capture the display or hide the cursor.

If you want the change to stick even after your menu-bar app has exited, you need to use `CGBeginDisplayConfiguration()` to get a `CGDisplayConfigRef`, use `CGConfigureDisplayWithDisplayMode()` to set the mode for the appropriate display, and then use `CGCompleteDisplayConfiguration()` with the option `kCGConfigureForSession` or `kCGConfigurePermanently`.

Comment: thansk I'll check your idea.